# How to solve analytically the following 2nd order ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Especially, I wonder that analytically solution methods, except that Matrix Method (eigenfunction method), for like following ODE system?

$\ddot{x}_1(t)+b_1x_1(t)-b_2x_2(t)=f_1(t)$

$\ddot{x}_2(t)+b_3x_2(t)-b_4x_1(t)=f_2(t)$

where $b_i$ are constants for $i=1,2,3,4$.

I know that the question is specialized by giving constants $b_i$, $f_1(t),f_2(t)$ and initial conditions. But I want to learn the logic of general form and which solution methods can be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the method which often works (when the matrix below is diagonalizable). You have 
$$\ddot{X}(t)+LX(t)=F(t)$$
Where
$$X(t)=[x_{1}(t) \ x_{2}(t)]^{T}$$
$$F(t)=[f_{1}(t) \ f_{2}(t)]^{T}$$
and
$$L=\begin{bmatrix}
b_{1} & b_{2} \\
b_{4} & b_{3}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
You diagonalize $L$, $L=P\Lambda{P}^{-1}$. Then you let $X(t)=PY(t)$, so that
$$P\ddot{Y}(t)+P\Lambda{Y}(t)=F(t)$$
Then you multiply the equation by $P^{-1}$ from the left to give
$$\ddot{Y}(t)+\Lambda{Y}(t)=K(t)$$
Where
$$K(t)=P^{-1}F(t)$$
Then 
$$Y(t)=Y_{0}(t)+\int\mathcal{G}(t-t')K(t'){dt'}$$
Where $Y_{0}(t)$ is the solution to the homogeneous equation
$$\ddot{Y}_{0}(t)+\Lambda{Y_{0}(t)}=0$$
and $\mathcal{G}(t-t')$ is the Green's tensor
$$\ddot{\mathcal{G}}(t-t')+\Lambda\mathcal{G}(t-t')=\delta(t-t')$$
So the solution is
$$X(t)=PY_{0}+\int{P}\mathcal{G}(t-t')P^{-1}F(t){dt'}$$

Comment: As I know, the solution can be written as $Y(t)=Y_{0}(t)+\int e^{(t-t')}K(t'){dt'}$, right? (I don' t understand the part including Green's Tensor. Could you offer some books or notes to study your solution method)

Comment: You may think of this $\mathcal{G}$ as being a $2\times2$ matrix. The equation, when written for the components, reads as $$\ddot{\mathcal{G}}_{kl}+\Lambda_{kk}\mathcal{G}_{kl}=\delta(t-t')$$
The solution is trivial (if you know about the Green's functions) 
$${G}_{kl}(t-t')=\frac{\sin(\Lambda_{kk}[t-t'])}{\Lambda_{kk}}\theta(t-t')$$

Answer (score 2):

Using the differentiation operator $D$, rewrite the system as

$$\begin{cases}(D^2+b_1)x_1-b_2x_2=f_1,\\-b_4x_1+(D^2+b_3)x_2=f_2.\end{cases}$$

Then eliminate $x_2$ by forming a linear combination,

$$((D^2+b_3)(D^2+b_1)-b_2b_4)x_1=(D^2+b_3)f_1+b_2f_2.$$

This is an ODE of the fourth order. Its characteristic polynomial is biquadratic (you see it on the left-hand side).

Comment: I can' t find the root of the characteristic polynomial, so can't find the general solution. If you help me, I am really very thankful.

Comment: @HD239 Lookup how to solve a biquadratic equation, this is easy.

Comment: I can solve biquadratic equation, but I can' t understand what is the characteristic equation in here. (The right-hand side of the equation makes me confused) (specially, the term $(D^2+b_3)f_1$

Comment: @HD239: the characteristic equation has nothing to do with the RHS.

Answer (score 1):

1. Convert the system to a first order system of four equations by introducing the new unknown functions $y_1=\dot x_1$, $y_2=\dot x_2$, and then use matrix methods.
2. Derivate one equation (say the first one) twice to obtain a fourth order differential equation in $x_1$:
   $$
   x_i^{(4)}+b_1\,\ddot x_1-b_2\,\ddot x_2=\ddot f_1.
   $$
   From the second equation $\ddot x_2=f_2-b_3\,x_2+b_4\,x_1$, and from the first $x_2=(\ddot x_1+b_1\,x_1-f_1)/b_2$.

Comment: I understand Matrix Method. I have a question regarding your second method. I did what you said and I got  $x^{(4)}_1+(b_1+b_3)\ddot{x}_1-(b_1b_3+b_4b_2)x_1=\ddot{f}_1+b_3f_1+b_2f_2$. Could you help me for the rest of solution?

Comment: This is a linear equation with constant coefficients. To solve the homogeneous equation look for solutions of the form $x=e^{rt}$. For the complete equation, there are two possible methods: variation of constants (also known as Lagrange method) and undetermined coefficients.

Comment: In undetermined coefficients method, How can we select particular solution? (Because $\ddot{f}_1, f_1, f_2 $ is not known in RHS)

Comment: In that case you cannot use it.

Comment: thank you. do you know how can we solve numerically the ode system?